# What is the probability for each person in line to get in the club?

Tags: probability, statistics

Assuming that there are 11 slots in the club with 15 people in line. If randomly selected, I have calculated that their probability of "getting in" is .73

Now what if these 15 applicants are already "in order" since they are in line and the 11 slots has a .80 chance to vary by 2 slots more or less (for some external and independent reasons).

What is the approach or how do I estimate the probability of each person in line from 1 to 15 getting in the club?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 9 people always go inside the club so their probability is 1. From the 10th person onwards, we need to calculate the conditional probability of 10th person getting in given the slots have lessened, remain the same, increased. You can then apply the law of total probability over these 3 partitions.

Edit : Let $P(i)$ be the probability that $i^{th}$ can go in the club. Then $P(10) = P(10| \text{ slots increases }) + P(10| \text{ slots remain the same }) + P(10|\text{ slots decreases})$

$$P(10) = 1(0.8)(0.5) + 1(0.2) + 0$$

I assume that when slots change, they increase and decrease with probability $1 \over 2$. Can you now work out the remaining probabilities?

Comment: Thanks, will try to play with this. Just for better understanding, at any given point the probabilities between the 10th and 15th, it will be the highest for the 10th always right? and descending straight down to the 15th? @karmanaut

Comment: That is correct. A crude way to think is that the 10th person will go in if slots remain the same/increased but the 13th person can go in only if the slots have increased. The 15th dude is doomed always, so he can go home.

Comment: Been trying to work on it but can't figure out how to inject in the equation the person's position in the line. Any reference you can show on how to go about this? @Karmanaut

Comment: Check the latest update @Lyle

Comment: Thank you so much. Really make sense now. @karmanaut

Comment: I know it's been a couple of months but would you be able to clarify which part of this formula that considers the person's position in line? I actually made another question that clarifies the scenario using total probabilities. If  they're not in line, then it would be easy. But say if they are waitlisted following a list on who comes first, that's where I encounter a problem. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646468/probabilities-of-each-waitlist-person